# Scala - Convert Seq[Int] to a single number consisting numbers in the Seq

Tags: scala, functional-programming, seq

In Scala, how can I convert a Seq[Int] to a single number consisting of the numbers in the Seq.

e.g.

`Seq(2,3,45,10)` to `234510` as a number

A straightforward method is

`Seq(2,3,45,10).mkString.toLong`

Is there a better and perhaps more performant/functional way?

Comment: I would argue that performance-wise, your suggested method is very good. It is also purely functional, so I wouldn't lose any sleep over it.

Comment: I think it's an O(n) so should be fine.  Thanks @Zoltán

Comment: In addition - regarding performance, you could only have memory problems if you had too many digits, but you would hit the maximum number representable by `Long` (`9,223,372,036,854,775,807`) long before you ran into an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: @Zoltan, I agree.  In that case I would probably resort to BigDecimal.

Comment: Note that this approach is **not total**. It will fail with a negative number, as so: `scala> Seq(666, -6, 5).mkString.toLong
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "666-65"`

Comment: That's right, @KevinMeredith.  I am assming here that the Seq will be that of positive integers.

Answer (score 5):

```
Seq(2,3,45,10).reduce((x,y) =>  x * math.pow(10,math.floor(math.log10(y)) + 1).toInt + y)
```

or

```
Seq(2,3,45,10).map(BigDecimal(_)).reduce((x,y) =>  x * BigDecimal(10).pow(y.precision) + y)
```

But actually i think `_.mkString.toLong` is the most performant, only problem it will work only for decimal representaion. For arbitrary radix you could do

```
BigInt(Seq(0x2,0x3,0x45,0x10).map(BigInt(_).toString(16)).mkString, 16)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def toNumber(seq:Seq[Int]):Int = {    
  def append(scale:Int)(n:Int, m:Int):Int = if(m>=scale) append(scale*10)(n, m) else n*scale + m

  seq.foldLeft(0)(append(1))
}
```